PostgresSQL/Ruby: How to get results for a nested SQL table?
I am running some custom SQL on on of my rails models because I need an aggregated result based on previous scopes.
events = Event.where(...).where(...).joins(...)

subquery = events.select("
  (SELECT MAX(t3.overlaps) FROM
    (SELECT t2.startAt, t2.expireAt, count(*) overlaps
      from
       (
         select lag(t1.dt) over (order by t1.dt) startAt, t1.dt endAt
         from
           (
             select events.start_at dt
             union
             select events.end_at dt
           ) t1
        ) t2
       where t2.startAt < events.end_at
       and t2.endAt > events.created_at
       group by t2.startAt, t2.endAt) t3)
").to_sql

results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("SELECT * FROM (#{subquery}) AS result")

Given a relation of events, the above query is supposed to return the maximum number of events that overlap (events which are actively ongoing at the same time).
EG: 

Event 1: 10/4/24 1pm - 5pm 
Event 2: 10/5/24 3pm - 6pm 
Event 3: 10/4/24 4pm - 7pm 

For events 1 through 3, the maximum number of overlapping events is 2 because Event 1 and Event 3 overlap a little bit. 

When I just execute the inner query as a raw query, it gives me the results I expect. I see each computed row has startAt, endAt, and how many overlaps are occurring between a given time frame.
However, executing against the ORM - I am only getting "1" returned for every Event record, rather than the getting the overall of the max overlaps from the inner query. The SQL generated from the ORM performs a SELECT(...all the inside stuff...) from events WHERE events.blah....
How can I rewrite this, while still leveraging the ORM so I don't lose any previous scopes, to capture the results in the inner SQL?

If you want help with an SQL query you need to provide us with an example of the schema and data. Postgres also supports the SQL standard OVERLAPS operator so I don't think you need to jump through this many hoops. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

I am going to be honest I don't even know how this is working currently since select events.start_at dt lacks a FROM clause.
